# Holonomy group of a fiber bundle

Tags: holonomy

Let $M$ and $N$ be a Riemannian manifold. Assume $N$ is flat. Let $G$ be a finite group acting on $M$ and $N$ as an isometry group. Assume that the $G$-action on $N$ is free. Then we have new Riemmanin manifolds $(M\times N)/G$ and $N/G$. The projection $f:(M\times N)/G\rightarrow N/G$ is a fiber bundle with a fiber $M$. Is the holonomy group of $(M\times N)/G$ isomorphic to that of $M$? We may need orientation data.

**Edit**
Since there is a serious confusion in my previous post, I made a substantial change in my question. The new question is very concrete and there should not be any confusion. Thank you for all the comments.

Comment: What is a Riemannian fiber bundle? Is it a fiber bundle with structure group lying in the isometry group of the fiber? I fail to see how your set up implies that the fibers have the same holonomy.

Comment: I don't know this is a good definition or not (I have a specific example in my mind). I think your definition also works. I mean that $\pi:M\rightarrow B$ is a family of a fixed Riemannian manifold $F$.

Comment: Do you mean a Riemannian submersion $\pi : M \to B$ whose fundamental tensor fields (as defined in O'Neill's classic paper on Riemannian submersions) $A$ and $T$ both vanish? The vanishing of these fields implies $\pi$ is locally a Riemannian product, as you want. I think your question is about the exactness of $1 \to Hol(F) \to Hol(M) \to Hol(B) \to 1$, as the result follows if $B$ is flat.

Comment: I am not familiar with Riemannian geometry, but your definition seems good to me. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @J Serrano: My definition is different from Paul's. You do not have to be familiar with Riemannian geometry but so far it is unclear what you are asking. You have to give a definition for which it is clear that the fibers are all isometric in the induced metric (else why would they have the same holonomy group?). Also what do you mean by "there is no holonomy in base direction"? Do you mean that the base is isometric to the Euclidean space? Voted to close.

Comment: The reason I suggested the above definition is that it satisfies the properties mentioned; all fibres are isometric. I think "there is no holonomy in the base direction" means $Hol(B)$ is trivial.

Comment: @Paul: a Riemannian manifold has trivial holonomy group iff it is simply connected and flat, so unless incomplete manifolds are allowed, the Euclidean space is the only possibility.

Comment: @Igor, perhaps we are using different definitions but, I do not consider simple connectedness necessary. For example, I consider a flat torus to have trivial holonomy.

Comment: @Paul: Then you are talking about restricted holonomy group, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy. Since the OP mentioned the fundamental group, I assumed his holonomy groups are non-restricted.

Comment: @Igor, what is the full holonomy group of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ with opposite sides identified in the usual way?

Comment: @Paul, you are right. My statement "a Riemannian manifold has trivial holonomy group iff it is simply connected and flat" was incorrect.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments and I am sorry for the confusion. I made a substantial change in my question. The question is now very concrete.

Comment: @J Serrano: by holonomy group did you mean restricted holonomy group?

Comment: Isn't it obvious when using restricted holonomy?

Comment: No. I do not mean restricted holonomy group.

Comment: Suppose $M$ is a point and $N$ is a torus. Then your question is: does every closed flat manifold has trivial holonomy? The answer is no, and examples are easily found by web search, e.g. http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0208205‎. – Igor Belegradek

Comment: I agree with Igor; $M = \{\bullet\}$, $N$ any flat space with non-trivial holonomy and $G$ trivial gives a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

A flat Klein bottle is a counterexample.

Comment: You are right. Let me add orientation data because I am particularly interested in complex manifolds.

Comment: Still, I believe, a flat metric may have nontrivial holonomy. Let $\phi:S^2\to S^2$ be a rotation (I want a fixed point to make the proof immediate), and consider its mapping cylinter. The holonomy seems generated by $d\phi$ (at a fixed point of $\phi$).